# Add external libraries in Spark scala from terminal

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to add external libraries for spark for that i have tried putting the libraries in `/usr/lib/spark/lib`. After successfully adding the library when i am
running my code i am getting **error: not found**.
I don't know where else to place the jar files, i am using CDH 5.7.0

Comment: did you restarted your cluster and check if it took place?

Comment: yes i did but still same issue i am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am found the solution after digging a little bit and i fixed this issue by adding the jar while opening the spark shell from terminal.

I used below code :

```
spark-shell --jars "dddd-xxx-2.2.jar,xxx-examples-2.2.jar"
```